# Axios not setting default headers in app.js when logged in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, laravel-7

The issue I am having is when trying to make a POST request I keep getting "Unauthenticated" error. This issue is because the `api_token` is not being passed.
If I make this request using PostMan it works.

Inside `app.js` I did a `console.log(axios.defaults.headers.common)` and that returns me the `X-CSRF-Token` & `Authorization Bearer xxxx` token.

Although, right before the `axios` call on the website (after submit), I added another `console.log(axios.defaults.headers.common)` and the only thing returned is `Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*'` which explains why the "Unauthenticated" error comes in, although I can't figure out why its correct in `app.js` but nothing get's passed after the fact. NOTE: I did not re-import axios in my component.

Inside my `app.js` file I have preset the headers for axios:

```
window.axios  = require('axios')

    let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
    if (token) {
        window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
    }
    
    let api_token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="api-token"]');
    if (api_token) {
        console.log('api_token.content',api_token.content )
        // THIS ABOVE RETURNS DATA CORRECTLY.
        window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + api_token.content;
    }
```

Website - component after submit:

```
async submitForm () {
  console.log('window.axios.default.headers.common', axios.defaults.headers.common)
  // THIS ABOVE ^^ RETURNS EMPTY HEADERS
  const res = await axios.post('/api/product/add/validate', this.form)
}
```

Comment: perhaps `token` and `api_token` are null/false/blank? does the code in the `if` even run?

Comment: @Bravo, When logged from app.js, everything is returned, and api_token.content, returns the token.

Comment: You haven't re-initialised or re-imported axios from anywhere else, have you? Things you can try is - try placing this `submitForm` function right below what you have in `app.js`. On a different note, you should create an instance of axios and use it in your application rather than assiging it to the window object. Axios doc might help you on this.

Comment: Just found my issue. There was another JS file that would re-import axios which overrode this instance.